# Execute JavaScript function after submitting in Oracle APEX

Tags: javascript, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

does anyone have a suggestion to address the order in which I can execute functions?

In Oracle APEX, I've added code to a button labeled "export" to capture the ROWID of each selected row in an interactive grid and then passed these values to a page item. The objective is to execute a process that requires a submit. Additionally, I've created a JavaScript function called `downloadFile()` that generates a file download. Now, the challenge is to ensure that the `downloadFile()` function is executed only after the submit. However, I wish to keep just one button that, when clicked, passes the values to page items, submits the page, and then executes the `downloadFile()` function.

I've tried declaring the function as a global in the page, in the JavaScript section (Function and Global Variable Declaration), and called the function after the submit in the button. However, this results in a blank file because it all runs together, and the values are set in the page item after the file generation. I've also tried adding the submit to the click event of the `APEX$ROW_SELECTOR` column, but it only works for one row at a time since the selection is cleared after each submit.

I've managed to make it work with two buttons. Clicking the first one captures the ROWID of the selected rows in the grid, applies the submit, and then clicking the second button executes the `downloadFile()` function, generating the file. However, I don't want to have two buttons for this.

How can I ensure that the `downloadFile()` function is executed only after the submit, while maintaining just one button for this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea you have in mind cannot work for the following reason. In APEX there are 3 phases in the lifecycle of a page.

- phase 1: **show page**. In this phase the rendering is done from the metadata stored in the database. All (before render) page processes/computations/branches are executed and the DOM is rendered. After this process the page is ready in the browser for use.
- phase 2: when the page is rendered. The DOM is rendered and available for use. User interaction is possible and javascript can be executed on the page. *This is the only phase in which client side javascript can be executed.*
- phase 3: **accept page**. This is what is happening after the page is submitted. Any after submit processes (validations/computations/page processing/branches) are then executed.

Those 3 phases always happen in that order and cannot overlap.

Javascript can only be executed in phase 2. Once phase 3 is started, the server is doing it's business and the DOM is no longer accessible. The solution you are thinking of requires javascript (only possible in phase 2) to happen after something happened in phase 3.

A possible workaround is to set a page item or request value on submit and then execute the javascript function on page load when certain conditions are met. This can be done with a dynamic action on page initialization that has a serverside condition.

Comment: I understand, thank you for the explanation.

I applied JavaScript to the page load, and it is executed every time the page is loaded, so sometimes, even without clicking the button, it would generate a blank file when refreshing the page. I'm trying to find a way to keep the selection box of "APEX$ROW_SELECTOR" selected even after a submit because I apply the submit at the moment of line selection. But I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: the row selector is part of the client side model of IG. It is lost on page submit. You could add a custom checkbox instead - that can then be set via a column value in the ig source query.